# Invitation Google Play Games unity Callback Method Can't Trigger

Tags: plugins, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I have some problem with invitation multiplayer Callback method in unity google play games plugin. the complete reproduce [here](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/857)

Any Suggestion ?